# Стили css принменяются не сразу

Tags: css

Почему стили обновляются только после нажатия ctrl f5?

Comment: в кэш заваливаются наверное

Comment: @АлексейШиманский <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"> это не помогает

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько вариантов решения.

**1) Использовать hash при компиляции css**

Настройте Ваш компилятор таким образом, чтобы при сохранении файлы пересоздавались с hash (пример: style.baedb042c16e1bf.css )

**2) Добавляйте версионность Вашему css файлу**

При подключении CSS файла, добавьте ему параметр ?ver={версия}, и при компиляции динамически меняйте ее, например, на текущую дату с временем.
(пример: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../сss/main.css?v=20211104165031">`)
При этом можно что угодно писать в версию. Можно сделать счетчик, и при каждом сохранении дописывать +1.

Если вы используете в своем проекте PHP, то можете воспользоваться [filemtime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filemtime.php)

```
<?php
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?ver=' . filemtime('style.css') . '" />';
?>
```

Подобный код выведет `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?ver=1203291283" />`

Comment: По личному опыту второй вариант не всегда почему-то срабатывал.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-F5 перезагружает страницу игнорируя кэш. При обновлении через данную комбинацию будет отправлен запрос на сервер для всех статических сущностей.

Comment: что тогда сделать чтобы изменения отображались сразу, а не по нажатию комбинации

Comment: опишите более детально свою задачу. Что вы изменяете в стилях? С чем это связано? да,и фрэймворк укажите